# integration of apereo cas with keycolak (as Identity Provider) via openid connect or saml

Tags: saml-2.0, cas, keycloak, openid-connect

I am getting below warings and errors while i am trying to connect with SAML

2017-08-01 11:11:59,912 ERROR [org.apereo.cas.support.pac4j.web.flow.DelegatedClientAuthenticationAction] - https://cas.example.org:8443/cas/login?client_name=SAML2Client | urlResolver: org.pac4j.core.http.DefaultUrlResolver@5ebbc212 | ajaxRequestResolver: org.pac4j.core.http.DefaultAjaxRequestResolver@7fc6bf26 | includeClientNameInCallbackUrl: true | redirectActionBuilder: null | credentialsExtractor: null | authenticator: null | profileCreator: org.pac4j.core.profile.creator.AuthenticatorProfileCreator@437895ac | logoutActionBuilder: org.pac4j.core.logout.NoLogoutActionBuilder@2326b11c | authorizationGenerators: [] |]>

.... ....

2017-08-01 11:14:37,859 WARN [org.apereo.cas.authentication.PolicyBasedAuthenticationManager] -

## 2017-08-01 11:14:37,861 INFO [org.apereo.inspektr.audit.support.Slf4jLoggingAuditTrailManager] -

WHO: harshad
WHAT: Supplied credentials: [harshad]
ACTION: AUTHENTICATION_FAILED
APPLICATION: CAS
WHEN: Tue Aug 01 11:14:37 IST 2017
CLIENT IP ADDRESS: 192.168.56.1

SERVER IP ADDRESS: 192.168.56.1

>
2017-08-01 11:14:37,876 ERROR [org.apereo.cas.web.flow.AuthenticationExceptionHandlerAction] -

Comment: I am using apereo cas 5.1.2 version  https://github.com/apereo/cas-overlay-template

Comment: and keycloak version is 3.2.0   http://www.keycloak.org/downloads.html

Comment: i tested with openid connect protocol and its configurations are as below (application.properties)

Comment: cas.serviceRegistry.config.location=file://D:/EBMS/cas_cp/
## pac4j web flow
cas.authn.pac4j.typedIdUsed=false
cas.authn.pac4j.autoRedirect=false
cas.authn.pac4j.name=liferay

Comment: cas.authn.pac4j.oidc[0].type=GENERIC 
cas.authn.pac4j.oidc[0].discoveryUri=http://10.10.180.76:8180/auth/realms/master/.well-known/openid-configuration
#cas.authn.pac4j.oidc[0].maxClockSkew=
cas.authn.pac4j.oidc[0].scope=openid,offline_access
cas.authn.pac4j.oidc.id=APCAS
cas.authn.pac4j.oidc.secret=c4f22e9a-66ac-4e84-8e7e-7c3d8fa2b0bb
cas.authn.pac4j.oidc[0].useNonce=false
cas.authn.pac4j.oidc[0].preferredJwsAlgorithm=RS256
#cas.authn.pac4j.oidc[0].customParams.param1=value1
# cas.authn.policy.requiredHandlerAuthenticationPolicyEnabled=true

Comment: i tested with SAML also but failed, below is the configurations in application.properties

Comment: {
cas.authn.pac4j.typedIdUsed=false 
cas.authn.pac4j.autoRedirect=true
cas.authn.pac4j.name=liferay
}

Comment: cas.authn.pac4j.saml[0].keystorePassword=changeit
cas.authn.pac4j.saml[0].privateKeyPassword=changeit
cas.authn.pac4j.saml[0].keystorePath=file://D:/EBMS/apereo_SAML_DIR/keystorePath/.keystore

Comment: cas.authn.pac4j.saml[0].serviceProviderEntityId=urn:mace:saml:pac4j.org

Comment: cas.authn.pac4j.saml[0].serviceProviderMetadataPath=file://D:/EBMS/apereo_SAML_DIR/serviceProviderMetadataPath/sp_meta.xml

cas.authn.pac4j.saml[0].maximumAuthenticationLifetime=10000

Comment: cas.authn.pac4j.saml[0].identityProviderMetadataPath=file://D:/EBMS/apereo_SAML_DIR/identityProviderMetadataPath/keycloak-saml.xml